# wsgen command not generating wsdl

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am using wsgen command to generate classes and wsdl for my webservice.
I am following the below link https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-wsgen-tool-example/

wsgen -verbose -keep -cp . com.mkyong.ws.ServerInfo -wsdl

But it is generating all class and java files but not the wsdl and xsd files.. I tried from 2 windows machines and the same result.. What am i doing wrong here. I am not getting any errors.. its only generating 4 files instead of 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two remaining files(WSDL and XSD) would be created in your current directory. The generated class and java files would be under package directory.